# C# MemoryStream TCP/IP overusing bandwidth

Tags: c#, .net, networking

I created a simple webserver which sends small images (~0.5mb) of a webcam to a client at 25 frames per second. However, when executing, I noticed a quite big delay (estimated 2 seconds over LAN) and when checking the bandwidth usage via task manager, I utilize 100% of the 100 mbps bandwidth. I am pretty new to C#/.NET and not quite sure why / how this is happening. This is the main server loop:

```
 image = grabBitmapBlocking();
// Console.WriteLine("FPS: " + Aruco.FpsCounter.CalculateFrameRate());
//image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX);

// save it to jpeg using quality options
m.Position = 10;
image.Save(m, myImageCodecInfo, myEncoderParameters);

// Send the length as a fixed length string
m.Position = 0;
m.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes((m.Length - 10).ToString("d8") + "\r\n"), 0, 10);
Console.WriteLine("sent " + m.Length + " bytes or " + m.Length / 1e6 + " megabytes");
// send the jpeg image
serv.SendToAll(m);

// Empty the stream
m.SetLength(0);

// remove the image from memory
image.Dispose();
image = null;
```

Can anyone hint me to possible issues?

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your posts in future. You've made plenty of posts now - easily enough to understand how to use the editor and take a look at the preview before you post, rather than relying on others to make your posts readable.

Comment: What is `serv.SendToAll(m);` doing? Does removing this line remove your performance issue (ignoring loss of functionality)

Comment: Indeed - basically we need a [mcve] rather than just a snippet. You haven't told us anything about how big the stream is, etc... please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: Thanks for the downvotes & rudeness everyone. I was quite confident that the code was not faulty in itself, but rather my logical thinking. This was also (embarassingly) confirmed by TomTom. Simply switched up BITS per second vs BYTES per second.

I'd appreciate a moderator also deleting the question.

Comment: Don't worry about downvotes @Aeefire - you only received one anyway. Yes, sometimes the tone here gets a bit snarky, but don't worry about it. The answer below was way over the rudeness line, so I have edited it (and the poster appears to have been suspended for a month anyway, so people get their comeuppance!).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Start with checking your math:

> small images (~0.5mb) of a webcam to a client at 25 frames per second

That is 25x0.5 megabyte = 12.5 Megabyte. Which needs around 125 megaBIT bandwidth.

> I utilize 100% of the 100 mbps bandwidth.

And you need more, as the math has shown. There is a reason video streams are ENCODED and not sent as assortment of bitmaps.

> I am pretty new to C#/.NET and not quite sure why / how this is happening.

What you want is a video stream, which is encoded using a video codec - which means that images with little movement as SMALL.

Comment: Uh, ahm...  this is now.. embarassing. Yeah, ofcourse. byte vs bit eh...Thanks....

Comment: I would check your own logic before you lambaste others. 12.5 megabytes = 100 megabit, not 125.

Comment: @ChrisBint guess it was a typo... no need to be rude ;)

Comment: @ChrisBint This is true - but ignorant. Generally you have various types of overhead here (starting with IP packet headers). Generally a factor of 10 is a very good approximation between "payload" and "network bandwidth". It is a LITTLE too high, but much less than 2/8ths due to various overheads.